# Can't generate different random numbers in Python

Tags: python, random

I'm having this problem in python where I can't generate different random numbers in a loop. Every loop generates same numbers. My code looks like this:

```
import random

class Dna :
    genes = []

    def __init__(self, lifespan) :

        sum = 0
        for i in range(lifespan) :
            self.genes.append(PVector(random.randrange(-10, 10), random.randrange(-10, 10)))
            sum += self.genes[i].mag()

        print(sum)
```

Here, I'm trying to generate random vectors in the range -10 and 10 but every different DNA object prints the same sum. Here is the main file:

```
import dna

def setup() :

    d = dna.Dna(200)
    d2 = dna.Dna(200)
```

And I'm using processing.py for this.

Comment: You're missing some vitally important code in your question.

Comment: Which one? If you're talking about that 'population' line, you can ignore that

Comment: What's the PVector object?

Comment: For reproducibility, you could use a seed for your random numbers. Otherwise you are not able to generate the same stream of random numbers again.

Comment: @MosteM Thanks for the suggestion but I don't need to generate same streams of random numbers.

Comment: @ibt23sec5 It's processing's built-in object for 2D and 3D Vectors

Comment: If you want to diagnose such things in future, try doing print(self.genes) at the start and end of the constructor, and watch it grow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`genes` needs to be an instance variable (one copy per instance of Dna class), not a class variable (one copy for the Dna class, shared by all instances).

```
def __init__(self, lifespan):
    self.genes = []
```

Comment: Oh thanks man. I guess I'm missing some knowledge about classes in Python. :)